# UIView animation causing label to twitch

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uilabel

I have an `IconView` class that I use as a custom image for a Google Maps marker. All of the print statements show that the code is correctly executing. However, the "12:08" `UILabel` in `circleView` keeps on growing and shrinking (i.e. twitching). I can't figure out what the problem might be. I've tried manually setting the the font in the completion block, commenting out the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, changing the `circleView` to a `UIButton`.

```
import UIKit

class IconView: UIView {
    var timeLabel: UILabel!
    var circleView: UIView!
    var clicked: Bool!

    //constants
    let circleViewWidth = 50.0
    let circleViewHeight = 50.0

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 47/255, green: 49/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 0.0)
        clicked = false

        if !clicked {
        //MAIN CIRCLE
            print("init circle view")
        circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:circleViewWidth, height:circleViewHeight))
        circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 47/255, green: 49/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 1.0)
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = circleView.frame.size.height / 2.0
        circleView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(circleView)

        timeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleViewWidth, height: circleViewHeight/3.0))
        timeLabel.center = circleView.center
        timeLabel.text = "12:08"
        timeLabel.textAlignment = .center
        timeLabel.textColor = .white
        timeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        timeLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        timeLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)
        timeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        circleView.addSubview(timeLabel)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

---

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        let iconView = marker.iconView as! IconView
        print("going to start animating")
        if !iconView.clicked {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                print("making this bigger now")
                iconView.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
            })
            { (finished:Bool) -> Void in
                print("DONE")
                iconView.clicked = true
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: why is `timeLabel.numberOfLines = 0` ?

Comment: Also, try adding the condition `if finished{ //your code }` in the completion block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but commenting out `numberOfLines` and adding the if statement didn't fix it